# Syncing all Resource Room calendars to all Users Outlook at once

Tags: microsoft-outlook, powershell, exchange, calendar

I have 200+ Office 365 users. I would like to force all the room calendars into their accounts. They have permission already to view and add meetings, but I would have to manually add Calendar>From room list to make the calendars visible to them. I've been searching in vain to find a PowerShell command to add these calendars to all users at once, but all I seem to find are commands to give users perms to *view* them, which they already have.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? Generally, the way to use O365 Room resource calendars is with the "Add Room" or "Room Finder" buttons, and you can see the room availability there. If you just want a calendar for everyone to share, then creating an O365 Group automatically generates+adds a calendar for all the members

Comment: Sorry I know its a bit confusing but basically: 

By default the only calendar you can see is the default meeting calendar Outlook.

In order to see the other Resource Room calendars (I will refer to them as Conference A, Conference B, Conference C, etc.) you need to manually add them in each Outlook by going to Add Calendar>From Room List and choosing the Resource Room you would like to add.

I would like to know if there is a way to do this in bulk, instead of having to manually set it one by one in each of my Users Outlook apps.

Comment: Why add all room calendars to Outlook? It would be against best practices, add clutter, and cause additional sync time for outlook to load every room mailbox, when the scheduling assist tools are all most people need.

Comment: Added Outlook resource calendars like Rooms are a user profile setting. You can use VBA/macros/scripting to automate it, but it has to run as that user account - you can't centrally add them to everyone's profile. Other calendars like Shared mailboxes or Groups will get added automatically when users have access. Outlook specifically *excludes* resource calendars, because they're already in a tidy list in the address book and usually only need to show free/busy times anyways

Comment: I understand it is not Ideal, I basically just do as management requests... They claim it is to avoid confusion (since the booking delegation is done automatically, not manually)

My takeaway is that there is no sort of setting in Online exchange, good to know where to start.

Thanks a ton for the info!

Comment: You cannot do this, it will auto-map that way for full control of the shared mailbox, like inbox and all, but for the shared calendar specifically, you cannot auto map it into Outlook like autodiscover does for shared mailboxes when configured. Write detailed instructions with screen shots, annotated and itemized, post with read access for everyone to it, and then have them try to add with the instructions. Have a set for Outlook desktop app and another for Outlook on the web. If they have trouble, email your helpdesk to get in the queue for support. Done!!